# Problem with monogame reference in monodevelop MAC

Tags: xna, c#, mono, monotouch, monogame

I've downloaded monogame, monotouch (test version) and monodevelop for MAC and I created a monotouch IOS project, I included the Lidgren and Monogame csproject inside my monodevelop project and I added the monogame reference in my project. But when I try to build it, my Main class doesn't find the Game class and Game.run();

My Main is the same code that I got monogame site:

```
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using Microsoft.Xna;
using Microsoft.Xna.Samples;
using Microsoft.Xna.Samples.Draw2D;

namespace Microsoft.Xna.Samples.Draw2D
{
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    class Program : UIApplicationDelegate 
    {
        private Game1 game; //doesn't find

        public override void FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app)
        {
            // Fun begins..
            game = new Game1();
            game.Run();
        }

        static void Main (string [] args)
        {
            UIApplication.Main (args,null,"AppDelegate");
        }
    }
}
```

and My appDelegate:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace testeios
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    {
        // class-level declarations
        UIWindow window;

        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            // create a new window instance based on the screen size
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            // If you have defined a view, add it here:
            // window.AddSubview (navigationController.View);

            // make the window visible
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what's happening, I follow every step to install it. has Someone the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not 100% sure but it looks like you are missing an include

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
```

Try that and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: I put what you said and I changed Game1 to Game and it runs! thx!